# How to insert XSLT reference into Django generated sitemap

Tags: xml, django, xslt, seo, sitemap

I'm working on django and have used the sitemap framework to build my xml sitemap.  Google's SEO guide recommends having an HTML sitemap in addition to an xml sitemap, so I'm building one.

That being said, I'd like to simply build an XSLT and reference it from the sitemap xml.  Basically, I'm trying to so something like:

1. Go to /sitemap.xml and you see the sitemap xml
2. Go to /sitemap and you're served the same xml, only with a reference to the xsl sheet which would result in html being rendered.

This should make it easy to maintain since I don't have to do anything to maintain the html page.

Any ideas on how to do this with django?  My best thoughts for now are overriding the default sitemap view and using python to insert the xsl reference in the generated xml.  Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just customise sitemap template: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#template-customization with a special url for the html sitemap and reference the XSLT in the header.

Default templates are in django/contrib/sitemaps/templates https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/sitemaps/templates

Of course you would add them to your own templates folder.

Comment: Perfect and probably much more simple than getting xslt involved!  I'll give it a shot later and accept once I've had the chance to work on it.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to set the content-type on the view?  I have it rendering html but the default view is coming back w/a content type of xml and not being rendered by the browser as a result.